# Displaying single row of sql query result in view

Tags: sql, codeigniter

In my view I'm trying to display just once the user_username at the top of the page,and then all the messages and the message times below. I don't have a problem with the `foreach($message as $row)` part and that is displaying correctly. However I cannot get the `Messages by <?php echo $message['user_username']; ?>` to display the name of the message poster. Any help on how I can do this will be greatly appreciated.

View

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> View Messages </title>
</head>

<body>
    Messages by <?php echo $message['user_username']; ?>: 

    <?php foreach($message as $row){?>
        <?php echo $row->text;?>
        <br>
        <?php echo $row->posted_at;?>
        <br><br>
    <?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

public function view($name){

    //Error reporting if no name entered in url
    if ($name == NULL) {
        echo "no name entered in url";
        return;
    } else {
        $this->load->model('messages_model');
        $message['message'] = $this->messages_model->getMessagesByPoster($name);
        $this->load->view('ViewMessages',$message);
    }
}
}
```

Model

```
 <?php
 class Messages_model extends CI_Model {


public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

//Return all messages posted by user with specified username
public function getMessagesByPoster($name) {
    $sql = "SELECT user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages WHERE user_username = ?;";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $name);
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

Comment: explain this **I cannot get the name of the poster to display outside of that loop** and add your data array too

Comment: `user_username` have one value or multiple value ??

Comment: Will have multiple values but will be all the same

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
Messages by <?php echo $message[0]['user_username']; ?>
                                ^
```

Bcz your array always produce zero index array

and your model should be

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: going this way,it would be $message[0]->user_username , but its not tidy way. I would even go with separate query to fetch user. Step by step.

Comment: @JL9 you didn't use `$query->result_array();` in model

Answer (score 3):

If your query makes only one row and you'd like to make it into array, Use the method below

```
public function getMessagesByPoster($name) {
    $sql = "SELECT user_username, text, posted_at FROM Messages WHERE user_username = ?;";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $name);
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

There are several ways to return data from the model,

1. `$query->result()`
2. `$query->result_array()`
3. `$query->row()`
4. `$query->row_array()`

The difference between `result()` and `row()` is `result` is used for the condition that SQL returns more than 1 row. And `row()` is opposite. That means just 1 row.

And `_array` means your can choose whether return an `array` or an `object`.

If you use the `_array`-free method, that means you have to access your result by `->` identifier. For example, `$result->memberID`.

Otherwise, the array is `[]`. For example, `$result['memberID']`.

Choose the correct one, and use them properly.